What does this error that I'm getting mean when I try to compile my vyper script in remix?
I'm trying to make a smart contract in vyper that takes a flash loan from aave, swaps on uniswap, then on curve, and finally returns the amount necessary to aave. I'm doing this so I can practice my web3 development skills by using a variety of different concepts like routers and flash loans.
However, when I try to compile this code in remix, I get the following error:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

I have no idea what this error means because nowhere in my code am I using a .split() method. It might be because of the routers but from what I have checked, I'm passing in all the parameters correctly according to the documentations.
Since the message doesn't give me a line or anything, I genuinely have no idea where to start with debugging this error, and I was hoping that someone could help me find/fix this.
#pragma version ^0.3.3
"""
@title Crypto Arbitrage Smart Contract using Uniswap and Curve with getting a flash loan from AAVE
@license UNLICENSED
@author Salmon46
@notice Vyper implementation of Crypto Arbitrage smart contract
"""

from vyper.interfaces import ERC20

# set constants to desired level
MAX_PARAMS_LEN: constant(uint256) = 32
MAX_ASSETS_LEN: constant(uint256) = 32

#initialize resource variables
POOL: constant(address) = 0x87870Bca3F3fD6335C3F4ce8392D69350B4fA4E2 #aave pool
UNISWAP_V3_ROUTER: constant(address) =  0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564 #Uniswap v3 Router
from "https://github.com/curvefi/curve-router-ng/blob/master/contracts/Router.vy" import CryptoPoolETH #Curve Router

# token addresses
USDC: constant(address) = 0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48
WETH9: constant(address) = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2

#initialize owner
owner: immutable(address)

@external
def __init__(_owner: address):
    owner = _owner

@external
def flash_call(
    _amount: uint256, #Prolly like 1000
):
    """
    @notice Make flash loan call to pool
    @dev Uses raw_call, since uint16 is not supported in vyper
    @param _asset Address of asset to borrow
    @param _amount Amount of asset to borrow (raw)
    @param _params Arbitrary params to pass to the receiver
    @param _referral_code Optional Aave referral code
    """
    _receiver_address: constant(address) = self
    _asset: constant(address) = USDC
    _params: Bytes[MAX_PARAMS_LEN] = ""
    #_referral_code: Bytes[2] =  0
    
    raw_call(
        POOL,
        _abi_encode(
            _receiver_address,
            _asset,
            _amount,
            _params,
            #_referral_code,
            method_id=method_id("flashLoanSimple(address,address,uint256,bytes,uint16)")
        )
    )

@public
def swapWithUniswap(amountIn: uint256) -> uint256:
    #Approve Uniswap router to spend USDC
    ERC20(USDC).approve(UNISWAP_V3_ROUTER, amountIn)

    #initialize params
    uniswapPoolFee: constant(uint256) = 3000
    amountOutMinimum: uint256 = 0 #REMEMBER TO CHANGE
    sqrtPriceLimitX96: uint256 = 0
    receiver_address: constant(address) = self

    amountOut: uint256 = raw_call(
        UNISWAP_V3_ROUTER,
        _abi_encode(
            USDC,
            WETH9,
            uniswapPoolFee,
            receiver_address,
            block.timestamp,
            amountIn,
            amountOutMinimum, #This is amountOutMinimum...REMEBER TO CHANGE
            sqrtPriceLimitX96,
            method_id=method_id("exactInputSingle((address, address, uint24, address, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint160))")
        ),
    )

    return amountOut

@public
def swapWithCurve(amount_In: uint256) -> uint256:
    #Approve Curve Router to spend Wrapped ether
    ERC20(WETH9).approve(CryptoPoolETH, amount_In)

    #initalize paramss
    _route: address[11] = [
            '0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2',   # initial token: wETH
            '0x7f86bf177dd4f3494b841a37e810a34dd56c829b',   # pool1: TricryptoUSDC (USDC, wBTC, wETH)
            '0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48',   # output token: USDC
            '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 
            '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 
            '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
            '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
            '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
            '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
            '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
            '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        ]
    _swap_params: uint256[5][5] = [
        [2, 0, 1, 3, 3], #1st element is token index of WETH in the TricryptoUSDC pool. 2nd element is the token index of USDC in the same pool. 3rd element is the type of swap --just a standard token exchange--. 4th element is the type of pool --using a TriCrypto pool. 5th elemnt is how many coins are in the pool --3 coins.
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #Only doing 1 swap so that's why these are all empty
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]
    _expected: uint256 = 0 #Same thing as amountOutMinimum...ALSO REMEMBER TO CHANGE
    _pools: address[5] = [
        '0x7f86bf177dd4f3494b841a37e810a34dd56c829b', #TricryptoUSDC pool address
        '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
    ]
    _receiver_address: constant(address) = self

    amount_Out: uint256 = CryptoPoolETH.exchange(
        _route,
        _swap_params,
        amount_In,
        _expected, 
        _pools, #Empty for pools since we are only using 1 pool aka only need this parameter for swap type 3
        _receiver_address
    )

    return amount_owed

@external
def executeOperation(
    _asset: address,
    _amount: uint256,
    _premium: uint256,
    _initiator: address, 
    _params: Bytes[MAX_PARAMS_LEN]
) -> bool: 
    """
    @notice Executes logic with borrowed asset and set approval
    @dev This method is called by the Aave Pool
    @param _asset Addresses of asset borrowed
    @param _amount Amount of asset borrowed (raw)
    @param _premium Premium owed for asset borrowed (raw)
    @param _initiator Address of the initiator of the flash loan
    @param _params Arbitrary params passed by the initiator
    @return True if execution success
    """
    # conduct logic
    postUniValue = swapWithUniswap(_amount)
    finalAmount = swapWithCurve(postUniValue)

    # approve transfer back to pool
    amount_owed: uint256 = _amount + _premium
    ERC20(_asset).approve(POOL, amount_owed)      

    return True

Strategy 1. Looking at the parameters. I found out I had some errors when passing in arguments for the parameters, so I made sure to go through the documentation and correct the arguments according to the documentation.
Strategy 2. Formatting. I reformatted my code so that function definitions and the overall logic was written in the order that it would occur chronologically.
No matter what I do, I get the same error whenever I try to compile.

That is a runtime error. It can't happen when ever you compile, as it happens when the code is actually executing and tries to use the split() method of a null object.

@KenWhite I don't understand? If this can't happen whenever I try to compile, why is it happening?

Runtime errors happen when code runs. Compiling doesn't run the code.
